# How to copy words from .txt file into an array. Then print each word on a separate line

Tags: c++, arrays, string, console

The goal is to read a set of strings from a file called "words.txt" and save each word into the array strings. However I am have trouble saving and printing the words to the console. I think the problem is within my GetStrings function but I can't figure out why. Nothing prints out to the console when the PrintStrings function is called. Which makes me think that either nothing is being saved into the array or the print function is not correct.

```
int main ()
{
    int count = 0;
    string strings [MAXSTRINGS];
    GetStrings(strings);
    // cout << strings[1];
    PrintStrings(strings, count);
    return 0;
}

int GetStrings (string S [])
{
    ifstream input ("words.txt");
    int count = 0;
    while (input >> S[count])
    {
        count++;
    }
    input.close ();
    return 0;
}

void PrintStrings (string S [], int C)
{
    int w = 0;
    while (w < C)
    {
        cout << S[w] << endl;
        w++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your array is **not** `MAXSTRINGS`! That's the length of the array. Your array is called `strings`.

Comment: Voting to close this as:
*Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).*

Comment: Ah my bad that was a typo on my part!

Comment: That's not the bad part. The bad part is that you don't describe what goes wrong, what you've tried to solve this, and where you think things go wrong! If you describe that, people will be able to help you.

Comment: Okay, I will try and go into more detail as to what the problem specifically is.

Comment: I suggest searching StackOverflow for "c++ read file strings".  If you search first, you will get faster information than posting an almost duplicate question.

Comment: BTW, when you used the debugger, which lines are causing the issues?  What were the values of the varables?  You did use a debugger before posting, yes?

Comment: So why does `GetStrings()` always return 0?  I recommend either it return the `count` variable or declare it as a `void` function.  You are not using the return value in `main` anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is local variables.  Variables declared inside functions cannot be used by other functions:

```
int GetStrings (string S [])
{
    ifstream input ("words.txt");
/* --> */    int count = 0;
```

Here's where it's used:

```
PrintStrings(strings, count);
```

The variable `count` inside the function `GetStrings` is a different variable than the one in `main`.

If you want a function to modify an external (to the function) variable, pass it by reference:

```
  int GetStrings (string S [], int& count)
```

I recommend exchanging the array for `std::vector`.  The `std::vector` maintains its count and you can access it by using `std::vector::size()`.