# How can i copy one line from a .txt file into an array?

Tags: c++

I have 2 text files which I have opened up, and I want to copy the contents of both text files into an output file. Here is what I have got so far.

```
printf("\nWhat is the name of the output file you want to use? (with file extension)\n");
gets_s(thirdfilename);

fopen_s(&text3, thirdfilename, "w");

while (text3 == NULL) 
{
    printf("\nThis file does not exist, please re-enter the name of the output file you want to use (with file extension)\n");
    gets_s(thirdfilename);

    fopen_s(&text3, thirdfilename, "w");
}

if (text3 != NULL)
    printf("\nYou have successfully opened '%s'\n", thirdfilename);
```

I'm not sure whether to use a while loop to copy the text into the third file, or to use a for loop. I have already created and opened up my first two texts before the code that I have stated above. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: C++ way: `std::ofstream("third_file") << std::ifstream("first_file").rdbuf() << std::ifstream("second_file").rdbuf();`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to copy words from .txt file into an array. Then print each word on a separate line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32670811/how-to-copy-words-from-txt-file-into-an-array-then-print-each-word-on-a-separa)

Comment: Your title does not match your question text. Please correct it so that they both refer to the same topic.

Comment: See my answer: [Copying a file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5420317/reading-and-writing-binary-file/#answer-5422852)

Comment: Possible duplicate: [C++ - Reading and writing binary file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5420317/reading-and-writing-binary-file)

Comment: Somehow in the process of posting this function the outside got lost.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the *title* of your question, you can use the `fread` method of `std::istream`:

```
std::string filename;
std::cout << "Enter name of file to read: ";
std::getline(std::cin, filename);
uint8_t    data_buffer[1024*1024]; // Reserve some space.
std::ifstream input_file(filename.c_str());
input_file.read(&data_buffer[0], sizeof(data_buffer));
```